# Change attribute value of an XML tag in Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I'm trying to change the `language` attribute of a .ts file in Qt using Qt itself.

Here is the sample XML format.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS language="es_ES" version="2.1">
    ...
</TS>
```

I have tried different ways, but no luck.
Here are the methods I used.

```
FileIOError FileIO::changeLanguageOfTsFile( QString tsFileName, QString langCode )
{
    QDomDocument tsFileXml;
    QFile xmlFile(tsFileName);

    if ( !xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
    {
        qDebug() << "File not found." << endl;
        return FileNotFound;
    }

    if ( !tsFileXml.setContent(&xmlFile) )
    {
        qDebug() << "Invalid content in the XML file : Reading TS File. " << tsFileName << endl;
        xmlFile.close();
        return InvalidXmlFile;
    }

    QDomElement ts = tsFileXml.firstChildElement("TS");

    if (ts.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Invalid TS file" << endl;
        return InvalidFile;
    }

    // In here, I try to change the attribute.
    QDomAttr attr = ts.attributeNode("language");
    attr.setValue(langCode);
    ts.setAttributeNode(attr);
    xmlFile.close();

    return ReadSuccess;
}
```

The code runs perfectly, but the XML file does not get updated.

I tried the following as well.

```
ts.setAttribute("language", langCode);
```

But no luck. I don't know why this does not update the XML file. Please help me.

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable about Qt, but most likely the `tsFileXml` is in memory only, you need to actually write the (modified) XML to the file.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, but I think your XML is only present in your memory. You have to trigger somethink like `tsFileXml.WriteToFile(filename)` to store your changes to a file on your filesystem.

Comment: OMG, such a fool I am. Now I used a QTextStream to write it back and it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot.